# Ayuda con búsqueda de dos parámetros numéricos utilizando between en una tabla (en un rango)

Tags: mysql

Hola con todos me podrían ayudar a implementar un código para hacer una consulta apartir de 2 parámetros digamos que quiero buscar en un rango del 200 al 210 y que se impriman dichos números

Answer (score 0):

> La sentencia debe estar compuesta de lo siguiente:

1. Nombre de la columna con valores numéricos o fecha para comparar
2. Sentencia `BETWEEN`
3. valor a comparar mas bajo (para el ejemplo es 1)
4. valor a comparar mas alto (para el ejemplo es 40)
5. Para hacer la unión y comparación de los 2 valores usas la palabra `AND`

El siguiente ejemplo que te muestro busca de una tabla de productos, solo obtener aquellos cuyo precio se encuentre entre 1 y 40

**EJEMPLO**

```
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE precio BETWEEN 1 AND 40;
```

> Nota aclaratoria, solo te va a servir `between` para valores numéricos o
>   de tipo `fecha/date`

Answer (score 0):

hice una query utilizando el beetwen

```
SELECT s.ID, e.Nombre AS Sucursal, g.Nombre AS Proveedor, s.Folio, s.Serie AS serie, s.Fecha
    FROM Facturas AS s INNER JOIN
    Sucursales AS e ON e.ID = s.SucursalID INNER JOIN
    Proveedores AS g ON g.ID = s.ProveedorID
    WHERE  (s.Fecha BETWEEN ISNULL( @fromm, convert(datetime,'2002-02-11') ) AND ISNULL( @too, GETDATE() ) )
```

basicamente, hago un filtro de los registros que esten en dichas fechas, pero los parametros (@fromm, tooo) son opccionales, pueden venir tener un valor o no. 
bueno 
la fecha que esta "DE" hasta "A" 
ya siendo un ejemplo basico..

```
    select *
    from Facturas f
    where f.Fecha BETWEEN '2002-02-11' and '2005-02-11' ;

-- selecciona toso los registros que esten en el rengo de '2002-02-11' and 
-- '2005-02-11' ;
```

BEETWEN = ENTRE

Comment: Gracias yo tengo uno tambien pero para buscar informacion mediante java y sql, Pero ahora quiero hacerlo en php mediante una consulta pero las variables tienen que ser numericas. y no manejo muy bien php para como hacer la sentencia de parametros no entiendo muy bien el lenguaje

Comment: checa la documentacion de php, ahi hay informacion. http://php.net/manual/es/intro-whatis.php, la curva de aprendisaje es sensilla.

Comment: Esa query pareciera ser de sql-server. La pregunta es de mysql. Como sea, no responde a lo que pregunta el usuario